# How is a JavaScript hash map implemented?

Tags: javascript, hash, hashmap

I currently work with OpenLayers and have a huge set of data to draw into a vector layer (greater than 100000 vectors).

I'm now trying to put all these vectors into a JavaScript hash map to analyze the performance.  I want to know how is the hash map in JavaScript implemented, is it a real hash function or just a wrapped function that uses a simple data structure and a search algorithm?

Comment: There's not just one JS implementation, so there's no way to answer this. ECMAScript doesn't specify what data structure to use for objects, nor does it specify restraints on access time. Hashes are typical, but balanced trees could be used.

Comment: ES6 have pure Maps. The link describes differences between plain object and Map, key details etc: [MDN JavaScript Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Every JavaScript [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) is a simple hashmap which accepts a string or a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) as its key, so you could write your code as:

```
var map = {};
// add a item
map[key1] = value1;
// or remove it
delete map[key1];
// or determine whether a key exists
key1 in map;
```

JavaScript object is a real hashmap on its implementation, so the complexity on search is O(1), but there is no dedicated `hashcode()` function for JavaScript strings, it is implemented internally by JavaScript engine (V8, SpiderMonkey, JScript.dll, etc...)

**2020 Update:**

JavaScript today supports other datatypes as well: [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap). They behave more closely as hash maps than traditional objects.

Comment: Perfect. I was using $('div#someDiv').data(key, value) before and this one is much simpler and probably has better support for older browsers too. Thanks

Comment: is there a way to find the length of the map ?

Comment: @Sridhar use Object.keys(map).length

Comment: Note you can use a number as a key `map[2] = 'foo'` but it gets cast to a string internally `> map = { '2': 'foo' }`

Comment: @otakustay that was super cool feature that I came to know today :) Really I need to learn Javascript closely.

Comment: @otakustay : Nicely explained.. but i have one query is there any difference between map.set("a","2") and map["a"] = "2"?

Comment: in the given example , you cannot set an object as a key. But in a Map you can set any non primitive data type as key.

Comment: They can be used as hashmap but do they provide constant time lookup and insertions?

Answer (score 36):

JavaScript objects cannot be implemented purely on top of hash maps.

Try this in your browser console:

```
var foo = {
    a: true,
    b: true,
    z: true,
    c: true
}

for (var i in foo) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

...and you'll recieve them back in insertion order, which is [de facto standard](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164#c1) behaviour.

Hash maps inherently do not maintain ordering, so JavaScript implementations may *use* hash maps somehow, but if they do, it'll require at least a separate index and some extra book-keeping for insertions.

Here's a video of [Lars Bak explaining why v8 doesn't use hash maps to implement objects](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Erik-Meijer-and-Lars-Bak-Inside-V8-A-Javascript-Virtual-Machine).

Comment: "otakustay is technically wrong, the worst kind of wrong." That's a little harsh. It may not be 1:1, but for the intents and purposes of using a hash like a dictionary, it works in the same fashion.

Comment: Just want to clarify that this may be true of some implementations of JavaScript (such as most browsers) but not necessarily always true. The order of iteration over keys is not defined by the ECMAScript standards and may be any order and still be a valid JS implementation.

Comment: Separately from the issue of whether some implementations use hashing, it is not really relevant to the original question whether or not they also keep an insertion-ordered list of keys for user convenience.

Answer (score 24):

Should you try this class `Map`:

```js
var myMap = new Map();

// setting the values
myMap.set("1", 'value1');
myMap.set("2", 'value2');
myMap.set("3", 'value3');

console.log(`Map size: ${myMap.size}`); // 3

// getting the values
console.log(`Key: "1", Value: ${myMap.get("1")}`);    // "value associated with "value1"
console.log(`Key: "2", Value: ${myMap.get("2")}`);    // "value associated with "value2"
console.log(`Key: "3", Value: ${myMap.get("3")}`);    // "value associated with "value3"
```

Notice: `key` and `value` can be any type.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 20):

Here is an easy and convenient way of using something similar to the Java [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
var map= {
    'map_name_1': map_value_1,
    'map_name_2': map_value_2,
    'map_name_3': map_value_3,
    'map_name_4': map_value_4
    }
```

And to get the value:

```
alert( map['map_name_1'] );    // fives the value of map_value_1

......  etc  .....
```

Answer (score 8):

While plain old JavaScript objects can be used as maps, they are usually implemented in a way to preserve insertion-order for compatibility with most browsers (see Craig Barnes's answer) and are thus not simple hash maps.

ES6 introduces proper Maps (see [MDN JavaScript Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) of which the [standard says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map-objects):

> Map object must be implemented using either hash tables or other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test() {
  var map = {
    'm1': 12,
    'm2': 13,
    'm3': 14,
    'm4': 15
  }
  alert(map['m3']);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="test()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the problem where i had the json with some common keys. I wanted to group all the values having the same key. After some surfing I found [hashmap package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashmap). Which is really helpful.

To group the element with the same key, I used `multi(key:*, value:*, key2:*, value2:*, ...)`.

This package is somewhat similar to Java Hashmap collection, but not as powerful as Java Hashmap.