# get value with string key in javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to get an object property using a string representation of that property's name in javascript. For example, in the following script:

```
consts = {'key' : 'value'}

var stringKey = 'key';

alert(consts.???);
```

How would I use `stringKey` to get the value `value` to show in the alert?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the square bracket notation `[]`

```
var something = consts[stringKey];
```

Answer (score 5):

Javascript objects are like simple HashMaps:

```
var consts = {};

consts['key'] = "value";
if('key' in consts) {      // true
   alert(consts['key']);   // >> value
}
```

See: [How is a JavaScript hash map implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877666/how-is-a-javascript-hash-map-implemented)