# Is JSON in JavaScript stored in HashMap?

Tags: javascript, json, hashmap

I searched JSON and HashMap, there are many questions about "how to convert json to hashmap". So, they are different, and how can i use hashmap in js?

Comment: JSON is a text based exchange format. If your question is related to JavaScript objects, please precisely state the problem you have.

Comment: thank you~! I think i got the answer. JSON is a text based object that  different from HashMap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer would be “no”, because [JSON](http://json.org/) is simply a interchange format written and parsable as a JavaScript object. If you want something like a hash map, you probably would just use an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) not-so-primitive, defining and deleting keys or values respectively:

```
var mapObj = {};
mapObj[key] = 'value';
delete mapObj[key];
```

There is also the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object that might fit such an use, new in ES6:

```
var mapObj = new Map();
mapObj.set('key','value');
mapObj.get('key');
mapObj.delete('key');
```

You can serialize JavaScript objects by calling [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on them and then [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) them again:

```
var stringJSON = JSON.stringify(mapObj); // check your object structure for serializability!
var objsJSON = JSON.parse(stringJSON);
```

Serializing a `Map` is a bit different. If serialisable, you can do it anyway by using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries):

```
var strMap = JSON.stringify(Array.from(mapObj.entries()));
var mapObj = new Map(JSON.parse(strMap));
```

Comment: You should make clear that `Map` can not be stringified with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @Oskar: That is what I meant by “check for serializability”. The question is a bit broad, and if a simple `{}` suffices (which already is a [hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)), a `Map` is not needed at all.

Comment: thank you ~. first question on stackoverflow, and truely got help.

Comment: @曾彬炜: You are welcome for the answer and at Stack Overflow. Make sure you always know [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what to [do if someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) states clearly that `JSON` is just text:

> [JSON] uses human-readable text to transmit data objects

`JSON` is stored inside strings in Javascript. Javascript objects [are essentially hashmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8877719/2653611). You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert a `JSON` string to an object.

Comment: thank you~! I will search answer in wikipedia before ask.