# Access map attribute angular 2

Tags: angular, dictionary

I am new in Angular 2.
I have an object attributes which it is an instance of Map

I want to access to its value.

In the console, it shows: [image: attributes map instance]

InputFirstComponent

```
export class InputFirstComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() public inputFirstToDisplay: CustomInput;
constructor() { }
 ngOnInit() {
   console.log('InputFirstComponent: onInit');
   console.log(this.inputFirstToDisplay);
   console.log('attribute Object which i want to acces to its attribute')
   console.log( this.inputFirstToDisplay.attributes);
 }
}
```

I tried

```
console.log( this.inputFirstToDisplay.attributes.get('minOccurs'));
 console.log( this.inputFirstToDisplay.attributes['minOccurs'].value); // 
  print undefined
```

But the object is founded: [image: Attribute object has minOccurs and maxOccurs]

the object inputFirstToDisplay of CustomInput class:

```
export class CustomInput {

  constructor(public name: string, public text: string, public defaultText: 
    string,
          public complexType: boolean, public type: string, public children: 
         CustomInput[] = [],
          public isMultiValued: boolean,
          public values: string[] = [], public indicator: string, public 
          required: boolean,
          public isSelected: boolean, public 
          simpleTypeVarietyOrComplexTypeContent: number,
          public choiceContent: boolean, public inputQname: string,
          public attributes: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>() 
      ) {}
      }
```

attributes: Map(String, string) is an attribute of the custom input class and it which I want to access to its value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are gonna use String as keys there is no reason to use a hashmap, every object in javascript, as well as typescript, is a simple map. The only reason you would need to use the Map class is if you need something other than a String as a key.

Please take a look at this question -> [How is a JavaScript hash map implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877666/how-is-a-javascript-hash-map-implemented)

In your case try console.log( this.inputFirstToDisplay.attributes['minOccurs']); // without the .value

Comment: Please link the referenced question

Comment: Thanks, it works. In fact I choose to use Map because I recieve the input from backend and just i display it.