# Unable to solve Lonely Number problem in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In a given array of numbers, one element will show up once and the rest will show up twice. Can you find that number in O(n) linear time?

eg - `lonelyNumber([4, 4, 6, 1, 3, 1, 3]) // 6`

I am trying this in javascript and my code so far -

```
var lonelyNumber=function(arr) {   
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++) {
      if(j!==i && arr[i]===arr[j]) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if(j===arr.length) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
}

console.log(lonelyNumber([4, 4, 6, 1, 3, 1, 3]));
```

But this is having a complexity of O(n^2). How do I get it to O(n)?

Comment: Hint: use a dictionary to store already seen numbers.

Comment: I will google for dictionary store and try it out

Comment: Just XOR all elements, That is your answer.

Comment: ok will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hashmap for this. And the way to do that is using Objects in javascript.

Basically I am looping through the array and adding new keys if the object is found first time and removing keys if the object is found second time. In the end the only key left in the object is the result.

```
var lonelyNumber=function(arr) {
  var obj={};
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    if(obj[arr[i]]) {
      delete obj[arr[i]];
    } else {
      obj[arr[i]]=true;
    }
  }
  return Object.keys(obj)[0];
}
```

This should result in complexity of O(n).

Comment: thanks. But how is object being a hask map?

Comment: refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8877719/1298824)