# Why useMemo does't memoizes value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple example:

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const calc = (n) => (
  Math.random()
)

export default function App() {
  const [n, setN] = useState(1);
  const r = useMemo(() => 
    calc(n)
  , [n])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={e => setN(e.target.value)}/><br/>
      <strong>useMemo: {r}</strong><br/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why for the same dependency `n` it displays different results in `r`?
AFAIK, it should be memoized…

Comment: If below answers are useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If any answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (once the system allows that). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

From [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

> Pass a “create” function and an array of dependencies. **useMemo will only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed.** This optimization helps to avoid expensive calculations on every render.

**Example:**

when `n = 1`, `r` becomes `0.1234`

now when `n = 2`, `r` becomes `0.2345`. (dependency was changed so it will recompute)

and again when `n = 1`, `r` becomes `0.1930`. (dependency was changed so it will recompute)

---

Hence, `useMemo` is working as expected. But you may need a different tool to accomplish what you are trying to do (maybe something like a [Map / Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8877666/2873538)). Remember that `useMemo` is a performance optimization tool (it is not a map of key-value).

Answer (score 1):

Because `useMemo` will call again when dependencies change. When you change input, `setN` will call so state `n` will change. Then function in `useMemo` will call and return a new value for `r`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input onChange={e => setN(e.target.value)}/><br/>
```

The type of `e.target.value` is `String`. You initiate the state with Number 1, which is Number type.

So when you type the same initial value on your keyboard, you are actually getting the value as `"1"`.

Since the `"1" !== 1`, the setState trigger a change.

If you change,

```
<input onChange={e => setN(e.target.value)}/><br/>
```

to

```
<input onChange={e => setN(Number(e.target.value))}/><br/>
```

Now try to insert the same value as 1, you will see it is not trigger a component update. But now you should be careful as if you type a non numeric value on keyboard, you will get `Null` as the return of `Number(e.target.value)`. This will lead to not to update the state,

> Calling setState with null no longer triggers an update. This allows
> you to decide in an updater function if you want to re-render.